# Dockerhub automated build: BitBucket repository with private submodules

Tags: docker, bitbucket, dockerfile, dockerhub

I have a private BitBucket repository that stores my `Dockerfile`. This repository has two other private BitBucket repositories as `git submodules`. I setup an automated build process on Docker hub and added the public SSH key to my three private repositories on BitBucket. However, when the build runs, it successfully connects to the main private repository on BitBucket but fails when trying to get the submodules. I see the following error in the log file:

```
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://bitbucket.org': No such device or address
```

It seems like the build agent is trying to access the submodules via `HTTPS`, and obviously, fails as there is no web access setup.

Am I missing something or is it a limitation that I'll have to live with for the moment?

Comment: It seems you're lack of access credentials within the script / environment you're trying to use

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. My `.gitmodules` had an `HTTPS` URL for that particular repository. I edited the `.gitmodules` file and changed the URL to `SSH`. Seems like it is building now :-)